# Space in Function Call Parameter List (C++)

Tags: c++, swig

I came across some syntax in a C++ project I'm working with and do not know what to make of it. The compiler does not throw any errors in relation to this:

```
lua_pushstring(L,"swig_runtime_data_type_pointer" SWIG_RUNTIME_VERSION SWIG_TYPE_TABLE_NAME);
```

Notice the spaces between [what I assume to be] the function parameters.

The function definition for `lua_pushstring` is

```
LUA_API const char *(lua_pushstring) (lua_State *L, const char *s);
```

`SWIG_RUNTIME_VERSION` is a `#define` equal to `"4"`

`SWIG_TYPE_TABLE_NAME` is defined in the following block:

```
#ifdef SWIG_TYPE_TABLE
# define SWIG_QUOTE_STRING(x) #x
# define SWIG_EXPAND_AND_QUOTE_STRING(x) SWIG_QUOTE_STRING(x)
# define SWIG_TYPE_TABLE_NAME SWIG_EXPAND_AND_QUOTE_STRING(SWIG_TYPE_TABLE)
#else
# define SWIG_TYPE_TABLE_NAME
#endif
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

For further reference, the code is used in the [swig project](https://github.com/swig/swig) on GitHub: [luarun.swg:353](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/lua/luarun.swg#L353) and [luarun.swg:364](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/lua/luarun.swg#L364).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. `"abc" "123"` will concatenate the two strings: `"abc123"`

Comment: Do you know what the "stringizing" operator (`#`) does in a macro?  Plenty of links here and elsewhere with this information.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Is that what the `#` symbol is for?

Comment: @J.Titus -- Yes.  Read up on the C++ preprocessor and the symbols that can be used within them.

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Static string concatination.  "Hello " "World" is the same as "Hello World".

Comment: Learn something new every day. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The constant strings are cat'ed together

The following code produces output equal to all three strings in the parameter list.

```
#include <iostream>
void f(const char* s) {
    std::cerr << s << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    f("sksksk" "jksjksj" "sjksjks");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ (and C) will automatically concatenate adjacent string literals. So

```
std::cout << "Hello " "World" << std::endl;
```

will output "Hello World". This only applies to *literals* though, not to variables:

```
std::string a = "Hello ", b = "World";
std::string c = a b //error, use a + b
```

You can use `std::string`'s `operator+` for that purpose (or `strcat`, but avoid that if you can).

This feature is mainly useful when we have a really long string literal that doesn't fit on one line:

```
process_string("The quick brown fox jumps over "
               "the lazy dog");
```

It can also be useful with preprocessing directives, as in your example.